# How to run a java jar that writes records periodically on firestore database, on google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, java, google-app-engine, maven

I have created a java jar executable.
The project is a maven project.
It is running a task every 5 minutes and using this library (https://github.com/googleapis/java-firestore) it adds some records to a firestore database.
It is not a web app and it does not use any 3rd party framework.
How can I run this jar on google cloud?
I have seen that google cloud offers many options like App Engine or cloud run.
Which solution best fits my specific case?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Deploying your application to App Engine alone or Cloud Run alone might not be able to fulfill all you have planned.

App Engine Cron Service allows you to configure [regularly scheduled tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml). So, you surely could set up an App Engine Cron to carry out the scheduled tasks using the [sub-daily intervals](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#defining_the_cron_job_schedule) scheduling to allow the job to run every 5 mins.

Additionally, you can use App Engine Cron with Cloud Functions to reliably trigger a function at a regular interval as you could use the Cloud functions for the regular [writes to your Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659525/creating-a-document-in-firestore-using-cloud-functions)